# Invoking an action using jquery ajax

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery, jquery-ui-dialog

I am using ASP.NET MVC 2. I have a modal dialog (done through jquery UI) that contains two text boxes and a button. All the controls are inside a form.

I would like to invoke, when the user click the button, a controller action that do some operations on the passed data contained in the two text boxes and then return an integer value and a string message to the user.

Could anybody provide an example for doing this with jquery?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

suppose you have the following form :

```
<form id="ajax-form">
    <fieldset>
        <input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname" />   
        <input type="text" id="lastname" name="lastname" />
        <input type="submit" value="send" />
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

using jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
$("#ajax-form").submit(function(){ 

    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Person/Add",
            data: $("#ajax-form").serialize(),
            success: function (response) {
                // whatever you want to happen on success
            },
            error: function (response) {
                    alert('There was an error.');
                }
        });

});
```

});

Accessing Your Data in the Action Method.

```
public ActionResult Add(FormCollection form)
{
    string firstname  = form["firstname"];
    string firstname  = form["lastname"];
    // do whatever you want here
    // then return something to the view
    return Json(/*some object*/);
}
```

another way is to use Microsoft Ajax

```
<% using (Ajax.BeginForm("Add", "Person", 
            new AjaxOptions() { 
                               UpdateTargetId = "formDiv", 
                               InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, 
                               HttpMethod = "Post" }))   {%>

        <fieldset>

             // Form Elements Here.            

        </fieldset>

<% } %>
```

`UpdateTargetId` is the id of the html element to be targeted. 
The InsertionMode option has three values `Replace`, `InsertAfter`, `InsertBefore`

Hope that was helpful

**Update** : you don't have to return a Json result in your action method you can simply return a partial view or any HTML code as the response object and then insert it using jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

You may take a look at the [documentation](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-form) about how you could implement a dialog that contains form fields. And when the `confirm` button is clicked you could simply send an AJAX request.

```
buttons: {
    Confirm: function() {
        // read the value in the textbox
        var name = $('#name').val();

        // send an AJAX request to an action that will return JSON:
        $.getJSON('/home/foo', { name: name }, function(result) {
            // read the returned value
            alert(result.Value);
        });
    },
    Cancel: function() {
        $(this).dialog('close');
    }
}
```

And your controller action:

```
public ActionResult Foo(string name)
{
    return Json(new { Value = '123' }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the reference and the answer!